# MQ IBM integration bus with JNDI while connect with java faced errors

Tags: java, ibm-mq, jndi, mq

**We are subscribing the performance data from MQ for IBM integration bus with JNDI
While connecting with java application we are getting the below error ,when we check other forums about 2063 error ,it is related to AMS (Advanced Message Security )
but there is no AMS enabled in MQ
Kindly help us identify the issue**

```
JMSException :com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic '$SYS/Broker/+/StatisticsAccounting/#' with selector 'none' using MQSUB.
There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:213)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:113)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1034)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:134)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.<init>(WMQMessageConsumer.java:471)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(WMQSession.java:923)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:1176)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:1222)
                at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createDurableSubscriber(MQSession.java:505)
                at SampleBase.connect(SampleBase.java:694)    
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2063' ('MQRC_SECURITY_ERROR').
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
                ... 15 more
```

Comment: Have you checked queue manager error logs? Also there is "There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information." in the exception stack. Do you have any other application using the same subscription?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We checked on MQ server and there are no topic subscribers.. So the error message - "Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name." is misleading

Comment: Have you checked queue manager error log AMQERR01.LOG file. This file will be located in <qmgr data dir>/qmgrs/<qmgr name>/errors directory.